# Why these two approaches for computing sum produce different run-time

Tags: python, list, performance, optimization, sum

Why these two approaches for computing sum produce different run-time? **(5 times check)**
Both codes run on : https://colab.research.google.com

```
from timeit import repeat

setup = 'a = [1] * 10_000_000'

expressions = [
    'sum(x % 2 for x in a)',
    'sum(True for x in a if x % 2)',
]

for expression in expressions:
    times = sorted(repeat(expression, setup, number=1))
    print(*('%.2f ' % t for t in times), expression)
```

result:

```
0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.66  sum(x % 2 for x in a)
1.03  1.04  1.04  1.05  1.06  sum(True for x in a if x % 2)
```

**Another check but different result:**

```
...

setup = 'a = [0] * 10_000_000'

...
```

Result:

```
0.66  0.66  0.66  0.67  1.45  sum(x % 2 for x in a)
0.43  0.43  0.44  0.45  0.46  sum(True for x in a if x % 2)
```

**Third check**

```
...

setup = 'a = range(10**7)'

...
```

Result:

```
0.75  0.75  0.76  0.77  0.78  sum(x % 2 for x in a)
0.81  0.82  0.82  0.82  0.84  sum(True for x in a if x % 2)
```

Comment: The second expression contains a conditional whereas the first one doesn't - i.e., less work to do

Comment: @Stuart, what aboyt the second check?!

Comment: `sum(True for x in a if x % 2)`: in check 1, this executes 1e7 comparisons and sums 1e7 items.  In check 2, it executes 1e7 comparisons but sums no items at all.  So it's doing less work in check 2 than it is in check 1.

Comment: The setup is different. If x is zero then x % Y will always be zero. So there's probably an internal optimisation that means the modulus doesn't get calculated. If you really want to know what's going on, get the source code. It's available from python.org

Comment: you have to consider the fact the your experiment is testing a _pathological case_ of a constant list of 1's... and 1 can also be understood as boolean -> shortcircuitation. try to the set-up  `setup = 'a = [-1] *10_000_000'`, `setup = 'a = [19] *10_000_000'` or 
`setup = 'a = range(10**7)'` and you will get more balanced results

Comment: @cards, OK, thanks, why this happen?

Comment: 1 is an integer but also 1 as True value, -1 instead is False

Comment: @RanN the key thing to understand is that only items where the 'if' expression is True are included in the eventual sum.  So when the 'if' expression is False for every item (like in Check 2), the 'sum' function has no work to do.

Comment: @slothrop, OK, but without checking, we don't know that those number is zero, all these approaches is `O(n)` but give different run-time.

Comment: @RanN that's right.  We need to check whether the numbers are zero.  That check always takes some time, and **sometimes** it saves time in the summation step.  That's why Expression 2 performs differently for different inputs.  The saving might be bigger than the cost, or it might not.

Comment: If you retry the experiment with modified expressions (with `not`), `expressions = [ 'sum(not x % 2 for x in a)', 'sum(True for x in a if not x % 2)',]` then for list of 1s and 0s you will find the opposite behavior which means that short-circuitation is performed. The setting `range(10**7)` seems to be affected by the increasing amount of operations

Comment: If you care about micro-optimizations like this then you should either be using numpy or switch to another programming language.

Comment: Note that both are insanely inefficient because of the CPython interpreter. Once converted into a Numpy array with `np.fromiter(a, np.int32)` (which is a bit faster than the list computation). The equivalent Numpy operation is about 100 times faster on my machine: `(arr & 1).sum(dtype=np.int32)` (note modulus are slow compared to a bitwise operation). Not to mention Numpy is already quite slow as an optimized C code is even faster (3-4 times on my machines, so hundreds of times faster than CPython). Cython is great for such a thing (not to be confused with CPython)

Comment: Long after answering, I realised this question is very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68938628/why-is-any-true-for-if-cond-much-faster-than-any-cond-for?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, let's denote:

Expression 1: `sum(x % 2 for x in a)`

Expression 2: `sum(True for x in a if x % 2)`

Check 1: `a = [1] * 10_000_000`

Check 2: `a = [0] * 10_000_000`

Check 3: `a = range(10**7)`

Now, in both checks, Expression 1 involves calculating 10 million modulus values and summing all 10 million of them.  That takes pretty much the same amount of time whether the modulus is always 1 (Check 1) or always 0 (Check 0).

Expression 2 works a bit differently.  It calculates 10 million modulus values, compares them to zero, and sums a series that has entries only for the non-zero values.

For Check 1, this means Expression 2 has 10 million comparisons to do, and 10 million values to sum.  That's the same sum as for Expression 1 in Check 1, but with the added work of comparisons.  So no surprise that *for Check 1*, Expression 2 is slower than Expression 1.

For Check 2, Expression 2 has 10 million comparisons to do again, but those comparisons all find that the modulus is zero.  Therefore there is nothing for the summation step to do!  It turns out that compared *for Check 2*, the time that Expression 2 spends on comparisons is less than the saving it makes by not having to sum everything.  So for check 2, Expression 2 is faster than Expression 1.

*(Edited after the question was updated with check 3)*

For Check 3, Expression 1 once again just sums 10 million items.  Expression 2 does 10 million comparisons and sums 5 million items.  Since Expression 2 turns out *slightly* slower, we can see that the time saved by removing 5 million items from the sum is a little bit less than the time taken in doing 10 million comparisons.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very well explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you run the tests in a hardware, the runtime of different results can be related to many circumstances, here are some examples:

- processes active
- hardware
- temperature
- cooling system
- order of evaluation

But just in the part of the logic, the second expression is slower because the condition is evaluated

And, a `conditional` generator comprehension gets evaluated slower than a normal comprehension. Furthermore timing something in python is extremely relative to different things from the software to the hardware even to internal optimization.

Comment: both codes run in https://colab.research.google.com

Comment: The conditional does have a cost, but in "check 2" (where every value in a is 0), it saves more time than it costs, because it discards every value and prevents `sum` from having to operate on it.

Comment: Honestly, for sequential CPython programs like this, the temperature and the cooling systems should not have any significant impact on the result. Only the frequency matters and unless you run the script in a very very hot room (not sustainable for a human), the top frequency should be reached on mainstream recent x86-64 processors. Same for processes: modern mainstream processors have several cores (with SMT) and so the benchmark should not be affected unless an heavy parallel computation is run at the same time. As for the order, what matters here is only the frequency, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very well explanation