# Check if any element of list a comes from list b

Tags: python, list

I've a fixed list of strings, `pets = ['rabbit','parrot','dog','cat','hamster']` and I need to match another string `basket = ['apple','dog','shirt']`. This `basket` will be varying.

Typically `pets` will have 300 element string while `basket` will have 5 element string.
I need to find if ANY of the elements of `basket` are from `pets` and return true with first match.

I'm currently doing it like this

```
for item in basket:
    if item in pets:
        flag=1
        break
```

There must be a faster way

Comment: You can do `any(i in b for i in a)`

Comment: Is it too slow for your needs? That should take no noticeable time for 300x5 checks. You can write the same as `any(x in pets for x in basket)` but that's essentialy the same complexity. Switching to sets instead might give slight improvement, but for this amount of data it's not gonna be noticeable.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen They said faster, not slower.

Comment: @KellyBundy I can write `any(i in b for i in a)` way faster than the original ;-)

Comment: @KellyBundy is it gonna be any slower though? With initial testing they seem pretty equivalent.

Comment: @matszwecja Yes, both because of the additional setup of creating the generator iterator and calling `any`, and because of the constant interaction between them while running.

Comment: "Constant interaction between them" what? Testing the timings disproves your claims.

Comment: @matszwecja For the interaction, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68938628/12671057). If you share your testing program, I can have a look and maybe make the difference more visible.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "return true with first match"

Comment: @KellyBundy https://gist.github.com/matiusz/3b0b71e9cb2c7183ef602bb7863c8419

Comment: @matszwecja Set `M = 0` to see the setup cost difference. Set `N = 0` instead to see the interaction cost difference.

Comment: @matszwecja Where I test (ato.pxeger.com), the `any` version takes ~300 ns extra to set up, and ~20 ns extra for each `False` yielded from the generator to `any`.

Comment: 1 microsecond is sacrifice I'm willing to take for more readable code.

Comment: @matszwecja I might, too, depending on how often I do it and depending on the readability difference (can't really judge it without seeing their actual code, i.e., how each version would look in context). Also, note that if you take your program as-is and just use a ***set*** comprehension for `pets`, it does show a clear speed difference (since then those extra costs aren't insignificant anymore compared to the membership checks.)

Answer (score 1):

Since, as you said, `pets` will be a *fixed* list and `basket` will be varying, you should make pets a set so that it can be checked faster. `basket` should remain a list if you are only going to check it once each time.

```
set_of_pets = set(pets)

//then presumably in a loop where you have a different basket each time:
found = any(item in set_of_pets for item in basket)
```

The idea is that you only turn `pets` into a set once, which is *O(N)* (where N is the size of pets), and reuse it each time you check a basket. The `any` operation will then be *O(n)*, where *n* is the basket size, instead of *O(n*N)* if you kept `pets` as a list.

For further optimization, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68938628) shows that the following will be even faster:

```
found = any(True for item in basket if item in set_of_pets)
```

A future version of Python may conceivably optimize the first snippet to be as fast as the second one, so unless performance is of utmost importance, do whatever you find more readable. (And if performance is important, measure and don't assume.)

Comment: @KellyBundy insertion into a set is O(1). N insertions is O(N).

Comment: @KellyBundy I think I've seen your comment that set creation is not O(N)

Comment: @matszwecja That was back when they defined N as the basket size instead of the pets size.